# JSDOM error in attribute.js

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, jsdom

I'm using `mocha` for unit tests and trying to use `jsdom` for `html` elements on my unit tests.

I downloaded the `jsdom.zip` and imported the library for my tests, and get stuck on this error:

> jsdom/living/attributes.js:114
>       for (const name of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(prototype)) {
>                       ^^ SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

I tried to find the cause of this error message on Google but unfortunately I wasn't able to find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest JSDOM does not work with older versions of Node (the syntax error is probably the ES6 `const`). As the [readme](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom#install) says:

> Note that as of our 4.0.0 release, jsdom no longer works with
>   Node.js™, and instead requires io.js. You are still welcome to install
>   a release in the 3.x series if you use Node.js™.

Try upgrading to [latest Node](https://nodejs.org/en/) or downloading version 3.x (also, NPM might make this much easier than downloading ZIP files :)